# Vue Cli 3 - Typescript - Vuetify styles not working with separate template file with @WithRender

Tags: typescript, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

My source code is as follows,

```
<script lang='ts'>
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import WithRender from './ali-ums-progress.html';
import Constants from '../../constants';

@WithRender
@Component
export default class AliUMSProgress extends Vue {
}
</script>

<style lang='scss' scoped>
  @import './ali-ums-progress.scss';
</style>
```

**HTML** and **scss** files kept separate. Using **@WithRender** html contents are rendering but vuetify default styles not working.

Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution for this...

After installing vuetify with command '**vue add vuetify**' creates file '**src/plugins/vuetify.ts**'.

In this file, replacing line **import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'** with **import Vuetify from 'vuetify'** resolved my issue.

Comment: `"export 'default' (imported as 'Vuetify') was not found in 'vuetify'` ?

Answer (score 0):

The Vuetify plugin file must contain a **style import** like the following ([documentation](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/snippets/js/use_vuetify.txt)):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css' <------ here
Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
});
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Great succinct answer, just be sure to add the documentation link to it as well.
You should have mentioned the [Webpack install](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/#webpack-install) section of Vuetify's docs as well.